# CSV File saving as Creo Pro Versioned File

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

This is an odd one, I'm saving an Excel file as a CSV file, which is the required format I have to send this data in as. However when I save the file, it shows in the Directory as a Creo Pro Versioned File. I know that our Engineering department uses PTC Creo CAD software, but I have no idea why it would be saving as this file type, instead of a CSV file.

Unfortunately, I am on a work computer, so I am limited to some fixes, but any idea why it would be doing that, and how to get it back to a CSV file?

Comment: Your IT department should be able to solve your problem.  You can also set the default program for the file extension, or simple use "open with" and click the checkmark to always use Excel.

Comment: That did work. It was just odd that it saved as that type of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in notepad and you will find that it actually is a CSV file. For whatever reason, the file association for .csv files has been changed to the other program on your computer.

Comment: Thank you. My IT department was able to fix it, but it still was odd that it saved as that type of file.